# How to ignore/remove everything i did and get to one of the remote commit?

Tags: git

i don't want to merge, push, anything. I don't care my local commit or any other thing. My branch, My commit, i don't car. I just want to make my project updated to the latest version on the server. Just like i clone the project to my computer. How can i do that?

PS I am using SourceTree

Answer (score 1):

Follow this:

```
git checkout .
git reset --hard origin/master
git pull --reabse
```

Oops. This was not for source tree.

Answer (score 1):

Just execute the command(mentioned below) multiple times till you get confirmed that your local commit is no longer exists using `git log`

```
git reset --hard HEAD^  # move local commit one step back while removing everything
```

and then update the local repo

```
git pull origin <branch_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click all of your uncommited changes and press "Remove".
Then double-click the branch node you want. Voila!